# Avoid pulling files which are in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, git-pull

I have git repository and I am collaborating with other developers. I have written added folders in my `.gitignore` file to ignore them.

However whenever I do `git add .` , it adds the files from these folders. Also when I pull the latest code from, using git pull it fetches the files from the folders listed in `gitignore`. Is there a way to avoid getting the latest changes for the files mentioned in `.gitignore`?

My `.gitignore` file is as shown below:

```
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp
/db
/bin
/lib
/public
/test
/vendor
/.idea/*
.idea/
```

Answer (score 2):

[`gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is only for ignoring *untracked* files, whereas your files are already tracked in the index, so `gitignore` has no effect. What you want instead is to use [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) option:

> Skip-worktree bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead.

Pass file(s) as additional arguments to mark them as skip-worktree, e.g. `git update-index --skip-worktree file-a.txt file-b.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will definitely try that. Is there any example I could follow?

Comment: Actually, upon testing, this seems to not work as I thought. Unless you’re testing proves otherwise (I might be doing something wrong—it’s late), this answer will self-destruct in the morning. You might also want to try `--assume-unchanged`, which I think may work, but I also think is not really meant for this use-case.